# How do you negate regex within delimiter string in string tokenizer in Java

Tags: java, regex, stringtokenizer

Suppose I wanted to tokenize a text where everything other than [a-zA-Z] are set as
delimiters how do I write the sringtokenizer in Java?
Would it look something like this: `StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(data, "[[^a-z]&&[^A-Z]");`?

Answer (score 2):

Try regexp `[^a-zA-Z]+`

```
String text = "hello, world^ i love: #66 you";
for (String str : text.split("[^a-zA-Z]+")) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) based regex like this:

```
String[] arr = data.split("(?i)(?![a-z]).");

?i - ignore case
?! - Negative lookahead
```

What it means is that delimit on any character other a-z or A-Z.

Comment: ?!(x) means not followed by x, exactly as the name negative lookahead implies

Comment: StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(data, "(?i)(?![a-z]).")

Comment: ACTUALLY it treats 'a' as a delimiter

Comment: From what I see second argument of `StringTokenizer` is not regex but delimiter so every character this String will be treated as delimiter. If you want to use regex use `Scanner` class; `split(regex)` method from String class, or `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes from java.util.regex.

Comment: i just want stringtokenizer to treat everything other than [a-zA-Z] as delimiter

Comment: @ChrisOlszewski: From Java doc: `StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead`. So better to use String#split method.

Comment: @anubhava sorry for that off-top question but I see you (and lot other people) use `String#split` form instead `String.split`. Is there any difference between these forms? Is it that `#` says that method is not static and should be invoked on object, where `.` describes static methods? I tried to goolge it but without success.

Comment: @Pshemo: Yes you guessed right, usually `class.methodname` is used for static references but `class#method` for non-static methods.

Comment: @anubhava Thank you. Everyday is good day to learn something new :)